# Get URLS of files in Dropbox folder in python

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have a bunch of folders in Dropbox with pictures in them, and I'm trying to get a list of URLs for all of the pictures in a specific folder.

```
import requests
import json
import dropbox


TOKEN = 'my_access_token'


dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(TOKEN)

for entry in dbx.files_list_folder('/Main/Test').entries:
    # print(entry.name)
    print(entry.file_requests.FileRequest.url)
    # print(entry.files.Metadata.path_lower)
    # print(entry.file_properties.PropertyField)
```

printing the entry name correctly lists all of the file names in the folder, but everything else says `'FileMetadata' object has no attribute 'get_url'`.

Comment: and how exactly is the dropbox library supposed to know which file you're asking for a url to?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Makonede my bad, code is now attached.  thank you!

Comment: ok, so after printing the entire "entry" data list, the `path_lower` field doesn't give the correct URL I'm looking for.  the correct link should be something along the lines of `https://www.dropbox.com/s/d39bf4zqpqjr6mk/my_picture.jpeg`

Answer (score 0):

The [`files_list_folder` method](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_list_folder) returns a `ListFolderResult`, where `ListFolderResult.entries` is a list of [`Metadata`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/files.html#dropbox.files.Metadata). Files in particular are [`FileMetadata`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/files.html#dropbox.files.FileMetadata).

Also, note that you aren't guaranteed to get everything back from [`files_list_folder` method](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_list_folder), so make sure you implement [`files_list_folder_continue`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_list_folder_continue) as well. Refer to [the documentation](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_list_folder) for more information.

The kind of link you mentioned is a [shared link](https://help.dropbox.com/files-folders/share/view-only-access). [`FileMetadata`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/files.html#dropbox.files.FileMetadata) don't themselves contain a link like that. You can get the path from [`path_lower`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/files.html#dropbox.files.Metadata.path_lower) though. For example, in the `for` loop in your code, that would look like `print(entry.path_lower)`.

You should use [`sharing_list_shared_links`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.sharing_list_shared_links) to list existing links, and/or [`sharing_create_shared_link_with_settings`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.sharing_create_shared_link_with_settings) to create shared links for any particular file as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!  Here is the code that ended up working for me:

`list_of_urls = []
def get_picture_urls():
        files = dbx.files_list_folder(folder_path).entries
        for file in files: 
            shared_link = dbx.sharing_list_shared_links(str(folder_path + file.name), direct_only=True)
            for item in shared_link.links:
                list_of_urls.append(item.url)
        return list_of_urls
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))`